# Copy a set of different excel formulas down a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an excel sheet with 1000 rows.
I have a result column that has a formula in it.
There is a different formula in row 1 to row 5.
Then the formulas repeat in the same manner from row 6 to row 10 and so on.
I have used IFS method by saying =IFS(Q="1",formula1,Q="2",formula2,Q="3",formula3,and so on)
The problem is that these formulas are quite long and it will make the syntax and readability difficult.
What other options are available?

PS. there is no pattern in the formulas.

Thank you for the help.

[Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqArM.png)

Comment: Perhaps you could create a [Named Formula](https://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/named-formulas.htm) to each formula and change it in your `IFS` function. The readability should increase. The syntax would be easier, if you know how to work with Names in Excel. Just remember to use relative references on the Named Formulas.

Comment: This also works very nicely. Clean and readable. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Disclaimer : without knowing the variation of input variables used for the said "unique formulas", I'm assuming the is no relative value from other sheet/data connection are used)

Try this [Option 1]:

Highlight the 5 cells (the one with formula to repeat), 
then click on the small box (at the bottom right of the selection), and drag downwards (in multiple of 5 rows).

Done.

Or.. If you want to try doing [Option 2]:

> (Q="1",formula1,Q="2",formula2,Q="3",formula3,and so on)

Then you may use :

```
=CHOOSE(IF(MOD(ROW(),5)=0,5,MOD(ROW(),5)),A$5,A$4,A$3,A$2,A$1)
```

or in other words :

```
=CHOOSE([get the row number/multiples],[formula1],[formula2],[formula3],[formula4],[formula5])
```

Please share if it works (or not).

Hope it helps. ( :

Comment: Both options worked flawlessly and with extreme ease. Thank you very much.

Comment: glad it solves. ( :